# Change URL name with mod rewrite on htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect the some urls to others using the htaccess file. I want to show

```
http://test.com/news/david-highlights-unsung-community-hero/
```

when someone open the url

```
http://test.com/index.php?process=views/article.php&articleId=44102
```

using the htaccess file. Please let me know how I can rewrite the rule for such urls  in htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect that exact URL using htaccess, you can do this.

`redirect /index.php?process=views/article.php&articleId=44102 http://test.com/news/david-highlights-unsung-community-hero/`

For more information, visit: http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-htaccess.phtml

Answer (score 0):

*Please let me know how I can rewrite the rule for such urls in htaccess file.

In your .htaccess file add:

```
`Redirect 301 /news/david-highlights-unsung-community-hero/ http://test.com/index.php?process=views/article.php&articleId=44102`
```

OR

```
`Redirect 302 /news/david-highlights-unsung-community-hero/ http://test.com/index.php?process=views/article.php&articleId=44102`
```

302 redirects are good if you will do SEO for your site later, 301 redirects are permanent, Or you can use ' preety link ' wordpress plugin to get this done from wordpress admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^process=views/article\.php&articleId=44102$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /david-highlights-unsung-community-hero/? [L,NC,R=301]
```